# Poor peformance with an Mobility HD 4250

Tags: unity, 11.10, ati

What i can do for this? I have so damn laggy and bad performance with Ubuntu 11.10 and Unity like with 11.04. ATI Drivers installed, and Sync to VBlank is disabled. I really want to use Unity, but its so laggy.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting Unity2d at the login screen. Visually, Unity and Unity2d are very similar, but Unity2d is not based on Compiz, so it may perform better.

Comment: Yes, Unity 2D works OK but i would like to use normal Unity.. What is wrong with Unity because it has bad peformance with ATI?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have got some of the same problems with HD 4890 which runs poorly on Unity 3d as well with the latest propietary driver from ATI. When I had nVidia I only had to tweak compiz by editing the framerate settings in compiz settings manager found with synaptic, but this doesn't do anything for me with ATI, so I am also looking for a solution. "glxgears" caps by 60 fps, but still the animation looks incredibly laggy compared to earlier Ubuntu's which was about 14-15000 fps. So what's going on?

Okay I got a "fix" for my own case, which could help you as well.
I installed compiz settings manager and messed around with openGL plugin (texture filtering etc.) and got great performance after a reboot. Now I have no issues what so ever and I am even running 3d-accelerated virtualbox and hardware-acc flashplayer atm. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I have an HD 4250. The problem is fixed by installing the proprietary driver.

Comment: Isn't the ATI driver proprietary?